# E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-ros-base

Tags: ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to install ROS indigo on ubuntu 14.04. I followed the instruction on the page http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu. After I input `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full`. The terminal outputs:

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

And additionally I want to install `ros-indigo-ros-base` on jetson tx1. The terminal on tx1 outputs the same messege.

Is ros-indigo still available?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239978/e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-indigo-ros-base/) by [sclin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26162/sclin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-07-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-21**:
Are you running 32-bit Ubuntu (armhf) or 64-bit Ubuntu (arm64 or aarch64)?

**Comment by [sclin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26162/sclin/) on 2016-07-21**:
I run L4T which is 64-bit Ubuntu aarch64.

**Comment by [sclin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26162/sclin/) on 2016-07-21**:
Is there any difference between 32-bit Ubuntu and 64-bit Ubuntu for ROS installation?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-21**:
Not on `amd64` or `x86` (the 'desktop' distributions), but for ARM, not all packages are build for all architectures. See [Incomplete packages for kinetic armhf jessie](http://answers.ros.org/question/239466) fi.

**Comment by [emchenk](https://answers.ros.org/users/27501/emchenk/) on 2016-07-21**:
did you add the necessary software packages into your sources.list correctly and did you do
`sudo apt-get update`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I changed the system to 32-bit, and installed ROS correctly.

---

Originally posted by [sclin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26162/sclin/) with karma: 16 on 2016-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-21**:
Just to follow up on this, there are no binaries for ROS Indigo on aarch64.

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-07-22**:
Can you pls tell where can we look up this information? I mean I know that there is a web page that lists the supported architectures of the packages. Which one is that?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-22**:
The [Indigo installation page](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation) links to the [Ubuntu ARM installation page](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM), which lists the supported and tested platforms.

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-07-29**:
Thank you. But I was looking for this [page](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/)